# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadItem' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I have a flash player that loads a new movie when a thumbnail is clicked or any element with class of item. Works fine in FF, but not in Chrome or IE. Need help figuring out the error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadItem' of undefined'

Here is script in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var isFlashReady = false;
 function flashReady(){isFlashReady = true;}
 function showRegistration(){alert("showRegistration");}
 function registrationCompleted(){thisMovie("player1").registrationCompleted();}
 function loadItem(id){thisMovie("player1").loadItem(id);}
 function thisMovie(movieName){if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1){return document.getElementById(movieName);}else{return document[movieName];}}  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(
function() {jQuery(".item").click(function () { loadItem(this.id); });}
);
</script>
```

And the code from the page including the video player and a list of images

```
<object data="player.swf" name="player1" id="player1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" align="middle" width="853" height="480" >
<param value="player.swf" name="movie"> <!--was missing this var which IE 6,7,8 needed -->
<param value="high" name="quality">
<param value="#333333" name="bgcolor">
<param value="true" name="play">
<param value="true" name="loop">
<param value="window" name="wmode">
<param value="showall" name="scale">
<param value="true" name="menu">
<param value="true" name="devicefont">
<param value="" name="salign">
<param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
<param value="true" name="allowFullScreen">
<param value="xml=reach.xml&defaultId=1" name="flashvars">
Install Adobe Flash and revisit to watch video content. <!--This is alternate content, took it out and Chrome worked fine -->
</object>

<div style="float:left;">
<p><strong>Space Track</strong></p>
<ul>
<li><img src="images/spacetrack1a.jpg" class="item" id="1" title="Space Track Video #1" alt="Space Track Video #1" width="120" height="70"  /></li>
<li><img src="images/spacetrack2.jpg" class="item" id="2" title="Space Track Video #2" alt="Space Track Video #2" width="120" height="70" /></li>
<li><img src="images/spacetrack3.jpg" class="item" id="3" title="Space Track Video #3" alt="Space Track Video #3" width="120" height="70" /></li>
<li><img src="images/spacetrack4.jpg" class="item" id="4" title="Space Track Video #4" alt="Space Track Video #4" width="120" height="70" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: rewatch turtles 3, you already dead shredder!

Comment: WOW! Ok the problem was the alternate flash content sentence. Take that out and it works perfectly. I think that's the stupidest thing ever.

Comment: You mean the `else` condition in `thisMovie()`? Could you kindly do me a favor and explain how the DOM `<object` has a defined function for `loadItem(int)`? This doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @Shredder I edited my code and commented the problems. I was missing a flash variable that IE uses to embed the movie. Without that it couldn't find the object. When an object with class item is clicked it passes the ID of the object to the script so loadItem(int) would be loadItem(5) and then send that id to the flash object so it know to load that item of the xml

Answer (score 0):

Your error is being caused by this line

```
function loadItem(id){thisMovie("player1").loadItem(id);}
```

`thisMovie("player1")` seems to return a DOM element, and then you're trying to call `loadItem(id);` on it..which doesn't make sense regardless since `loadItem()` would just sit there and call itself. Idk what you're trying to do, but that should help you fix it

**Edit response to comment:** Sorry, I still don't follow what you're doing with `document.getElementById('player1').loadItem(id);` as in how it loads your movie or how it works in FF. Seems like an infinite recursive loop to me lol.

If you make the id of your images equal to their swf file names (minus the extension) you could do something like this:

```
function loadItem(id){
    var movieObj = thisMovie("player1");
    movieObj.setAttribute('data', id + '.swf');
}
function thisMovie(movieName){
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1){
        return document.getElementById(movieName);}else{return document[movieName];
    }
}
```

I've never seen the document object be used like an array, so Idk if it will work for the `else` condition in `thisMovie()`, but I'm sure you can make adjustments ;)

Comment: Hey Shredder, love the name and that you're helping a turtle out. I'm not sure I follow. thisMovie IS referencing which flash object in the dom is supposed to load the new movie. If I had two players on a page this would need to reference which player gets the call.

Comment: But you did help me realize I didn't explain that the ID of the image is being passed to the flash so it knows grab movie 2 and play it from your playlist. Oh id 3 was just passed, load movie 3. etc. So this error usually means that a resource can't be found when it's trying to load, what can't Chrome and IE find to throw this error? and why does FF find it?

Comment: @McPace I see, but why do you recall `loadItem()` on the player DOM object once you return it? I edited my answer, I hope its more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your function call of `loadItem(this.id)` shouldn't be 
`loadItem($(this).attr('id'))` ?

Comment: If I was grabbing the id of that element alone it would be but I already am referencing the object with a class of item, so it know what this is.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the movie variable which is required by IE 6,7,8 in order to load the movie. All modern browsers load the movie from the object tag, but I was stupid and forgot the movie variable. See commented code additions in original source.